# Assembling to absolute address in ROM.

Tags: arm, stm32, cortex-m, thumb

I am using an STMF4 with Keil uV5. I have written a firmware updater that copies the new firmware patch via an RS232 to RAM and then writes it to a ROM location at 0x08020000, a location above the end of my application code.
Despite being a copy perfect copy of code that I have tested at a lower address, the patch at 0x08020000 will not run and promptly hard-faults. I have set the scatter file to include the higher ROM address and the mem map ini files. All 40kb of the application is entirely in assembler for speed, in fact I don't know a single line of C. I am not using any libraries either!@$#

I am wondering how the processor gets the information not to execute at 0x08020000, yet happily reads the ROM at this location despite the fact that my scatter file and mem map ini files seem to be OK. 
I am pretty sure I can write some junk code that extends above 0x08020000, a lot of it, and I could erase the block and write over it with my update patch, and it would fool whatever is preventing my code from executing. But that would be messy. Any ideas?

Comment: did you link it for 0x08020000 or did you link it for 0x08000000 and are trying to run it at 0x08020000?  Show us the disassembly of the first few hundred bytes...

Comment: and since this is not bootable code (not at that address AFAIK) your entry point is different than something that you run at 0x08000000?  (the disassembly should tell is a considerable amount, if you cant disassemble for some reason (not using gnu tools) then hexdump the beginning of the raw binary file.

Comment: wait how much flash do you have?

Comment: you have RS-232 hooked up to the part?  that will destroy it...It cannot handle those voltage levels?   Do you have a transceiver?   Are you using the ST serial protocol to do this load or how are you loading into that flash space without affecting other erase blocks?

Comment: Have you set the VTOR to the start of your new patch?

Comment: We won't be able to guess it unless you **show us some code**. What is loaded at 0x08020000, instructions or vector table? How do you jump to it?

Comment: Did you add NVIC_SetVectorTable(NVIC_VectTab_FLASH, 0x7000);

Answer (score 0):

the potential answers are:

1. The linker script - define there where your .text section starts (and another sections as well for example .rodata
2. Compile using position independent settings (I can help you with gcc settings but not keil). I think this article is about keil.http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0097a/armcc_bcfjjdfj.htm

Comment: still has to be able to branch into a non-standard address with a cortex-m that is not a branch to 0x08020000 in this case (if this was built with a vector table, position independent or otherwise).  Im guessing OP isnt coming back though so will see where this question goes...

Comment: @old_timer - I agree very unclear question. And of course he cant boot from there.